# Fedora 25 Change from Python 2.7.13 to Python3 (broken by `alternatives`)

Tags: fedora, python, alternatives

So I'm starting out with python. I'm working on a laptop with a fresh install of fedora25.

I got everything running in eclipse with pydev, but per directions of the instructor I need to use python 3.4 or newer.

So I check what version I'm using. Aparently it's python 2.7.13  I thought fedora post 23 used python3 by default, but such is life. So I check here and askfedora and other sources for how to change default version when you have more than one installed.  And two of them suggest [How to switch between Python versions on Fedora Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-switch-between-python-versions-on-fedora-linux). Before blindly throwing anyone's suggestion into a shell I browse around and it looks like a pretty good site.

So I followed the tutorial, and now NOTHING python related works.

```
$ alternatives --list | grep -i python
((no output))
$ sudo alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.4 2
$ sudo alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
$ alternatives --list | grep -i python
python auto /usr/bin/python3.4
$ python -v
bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
$ python -V
bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
$ python --vesion
bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

It looks like creating the symlinks as directed broke the connection between the expected python source `/usr/bin/python` and everything that tries to access it. I'm sure there's an "easy" fix, but I have no idea what it could be. Help, please and thank you.

I thought using alternatvies changed the python to a set of symlinks and you had to set one (see code block below).

```
$ alternatives --config python

There are 2 programs which provide 'python'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/bin/python3.4
   2           /usr/bin/python2.7

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 
$
```

**So why are none of them set to "answer" when something tries to follow `python`?**

So I got out of the shell and used gui `Files` under `Activities`. Went to `/usr/bin`. Found `python`. Tried clicking on it; I get this error message:
    The link "python" is broken. This link cannot be used because its target "/etc/alternatives/python" does not exist.

I don't want to set the link to point at one or the other python, right? That's the point of `alternatives`, isn't it?

Comment: What `/usr/bin/python` currently links to?  And what that thing links to as well.  i.e. when you follow all the soft links where does it end?  Probably a broken soft link on the path.  The syntax is `alternatives link name path`, so does `/usr/bin/python3.4` and `/usr/bin/python2.7` actually exist?

Comment: So I got out of the shell and used gui Files under Activities. Went to /usr/bin. Found `python`. Tried clicking on it. And I quote: 

`The link "python" is broken. This link cannot be used because its target "/etc/alternatives/python" does not exist.`

So entering those alternative commands busted something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do this. Since Python 2 and Python 3 are not compatible, they're not good candidates for the "alternatives" mechanism. Too many packages assume that `/usr/bin/python` is Python 2, and a lot of stuff will break.

Since a lot of software is not ready to move to Python 3, Fedora couldn't just switch everything over. Instead, we decided to leave `/usr/bin/python` as Python 2. Python 3 can be installed in parallel and is found at `/usr/bin/python3`. Fedora 25 includes Python 3.5, so this should be sufficient for your class.

Just make sure to use `#!/usr/bin/python3` at the top of your files and to use `python3` at the command line.

Comment: (Also, `ln -sf python2 /usr/bin/python` to put the symlink back to how it was.)